# Mount disk image as normal user

Tags: mount, loop-device

I want to mount a disk image as normal user, not at boot. So far I added this line to /etc/fstab:

```
# <file system> <mount point> <type>  <options>   <dump> <pass>
/path/to/file  /mnt/point     exfat   noauto,user 0      0
```

But when I try to mount it as `mount /mnt/point` I always get this error: `ERROR: failed to open '/dev/loop8': Permission denied.`

To me it sound like only root can loopback a device, but I expected the `user` option to be enough to fix it. How can I have it working?

By the way I tried both `user` and `users`, I have found different examples about it, which one is right?